# Kendo Grid for Angular - Trouble getting row selection, paging and sorting to work together

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using the Kendo UI grid in an Angular 5 application. My client would like to be able to combine paging, sorting and the ability to select multiple rows in the grid. I've been through the docs, and I'm having trouble getting all of these features to work and/or play together. The closest I've gotten is the ability to select rows and have those rows stay selected from page to page. The problem comes when I bring in the sorting feature. In my example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efseq7) if I select a row on page one, look at other pages, then come back to page one, the same row is selected. But, when I change the sort, the row becomes unselected. But, if I go back to the regular sort, the row is selected again, like magic, but neither entertaining or fun.

Am I missing a step here?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that (per Kendo's documentation) I was using a key (defined in the mySelectionKey method) that was a combination of the pk for my entity and the current row index. When I sorted the grid, the index number changed, and my list of selected keys no longer matched. I changed the code to only use the PK of the entity, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the [`dataStateChange`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/automatic-operations/#toc-built-in-directive) event as seen in this [example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/automatic-operations/#toc-built-in-directive).  It handles all events by itself: filter, sort, skip, etc.  You can see how I handle it in my [project](https://github.com/EleMech/eds4/blob/master/client/src/app/kitting/kitting.component.html).

Comment: Thanks! I took at look at your sample, and tried to apply it to the one I had provided (updated => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efseq7-npnw9y) and it's not quite working. I think the issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to apply the new state passed into datastatechange without having the rxjs stuff to get your data. I've looked into using that event, but it seems kind of messy. I was/am looking for a cleaner way. Part of this is the way the project (which I inherited) has been done. I'm not really in a position to refactor heavily, so I have to roll with what I've got....

Comment: ... anyway, if you have a moment and can take a look at the updated code and let me know if you see where I might be messing up, I would VERY much appreciate it! Thanks again!

Comment: @JamesBender It appears you got it.  Good job!

Comment: Thanks! I felt kind of dumb for not seeing it, but the Kendo docs are kinda "meh" :)

Answer (score 0):

I have added below code in sortChange method now sorting is working for me

```js
    public sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
        sort[0].dir = sort[0].dir == undefined ? 'asc' : 'desc';
        this.sortDescriptor = sort;
      }
```